# GeoFire: Wait for pending Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, geofire

I want to find all nearby people, retrieve some information from the Firebase database and return the number of a specific subset later on. On the client, the data will be loaded from the database after the server sends his response, since my results are saved there and not returned directly by the server-function. I am doing this, so I can retrieve them as an ordered list from the database after all potential people are checked.

My problem is, that the `"ready"` function for geoQuery triggers, before my promises from `"key_entered"` are resolved:

```
var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve,reject) => {     
            var someDatabaseCheck = groupRef.child("path1").once("value"); //Promise
            var someDatabaseCheck2 = groupRef.child("path2").once("value"); //Promise
            Promise.all([someDatabaseCheck,someDatabaseCheck2]).then((data) => {
                if(data[1].val()){
                    validSuggestions.push(userRef.child("path3").update(myData); //Promise
                }
            },error => console.error(error));   

            resolve("Done");
        }));
    });


 var onReady = geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
        console.log("GeoQuery rdy");
        return Promise.all(promises).then(() => { //Called before everything is added
            return Promise.all(validSuggestions).then(() => {
                onKeyEnteredRegistration.cancel();
                onKeyEnteredRegistration = undefined;
                onReady.cancel();
                onReady = undefined;
                console.log("Returning result");
                res.status(200).send(""+validSuggestions.length);
            },error => console.error(error));   
        },error => console.error(error));
    });
```

So my next idea was using the `"key_entered"` trigger to retrieve the necessary data and save it in an array. Later in `"ready"`, I iterate over the array, make all the magic happen and after the loop, I make the `Promise.all(...)` call to ensure every data is handled.

But apparently, it is not that easy to solve, since not all promises are added to by `promises-array` (and thus handled by my `Promise.all(...)` call) when the loop ends.

**How it should works with the new approach:**

1. Find all nearby people via `"key_entered"` and add them to an array (arr)
2. `"ready"`-Callback gets called
3. Iterate over arr
4. Check if person fulfills requirements (Promise A)
5. Promise A resolves and the person is written (or not) into the database
6. Iteration-Loop ends
7. Final list is returned and function shuts down

**What happens with the new approach:**

1. Find all nearby people via `"key_entered"` and add them to an array (arr)
2. `"ready"`-Callback gets called
3. Iterate over arr
4. Check if person fulfills requirements (Promise A)
5. Iteration-Loop ends
6. Final list is returned and function shuts down
7. Promise A resolves and the person is written (or not) into the database

What is the typical way to handle this? Am I supposed to run the promises in the `"ready"` or the `"key_entered"` callback? Also, how do I ensure, that all my Promises have been resolved? Maybe I am just misunderstanding some basic knowledge about Promises.